# `:after` - psudo class not working with `input` element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a `close` button on each of `input` element by using `psudo` class `after`. but not working. same works with `button` element.

here i my code :

```css
.textBox {
    padding: 15px ;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.textBox:after {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #ff0 url("http://www.gentleface.com/i/free_toolbar_icons_16x16_black.png") no-repeat -30px -75px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textBox" value="mytext" name="" id="">

<button class="textBox">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use wrap `div` and set there `textBox` class instead of in `input`

```css
.textBox {
    padding: 15px ;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.textBox:after {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #ff0 url("http://www.gentleface.com/i/free_toolbar_icons_16x16_black.png") no-repeat -30px -75px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="textBox">
<input type="text"  value="mytext" name="" id="">
</div>
<button class="textBox">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I just look to have avoiding additional element in the form element.

Comment: but it must if you want pseudo to input